# Python: Checking whether a substring of one string is a substring of another string, conditional on the first substring being a particular length

Tags: python, regex, string

I have two strings like so:

```
23971500000239713000002344550000023971900000
```

and

```
23971500000239719000002344550000023971600000
```

I want to test whether there exists at least one substring of length 10 or more that is present in the first string is also in the second substring.  So The logical should evaluate as true since

`23971500000` is in both strings.

Comment: I think it should evaluate to false, because 3971300000 is present in the first string but not in the second

Comment: Sorry, I want it to evaluate as true if there exists at least one substring of length ten common to both.

Comment: I don't think the second part is well defined.  There will be multiple ways to remove the common elements, resulting in different outputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s1 = "23971500000239713000002344550000023971900000"

s2 = "23971500000239719000002344550000023971600000"

test  = (s1[x:x+10] for x in xrange(len(s1)-9))
print(any(x in s2 for x in test))
```

Comment: you improve code but still it generate only subsets with len `10` not more !

Comment: @Kasra if there is not  a substring of length ten then there won't be a substring of eleven or longer

Comment: any way you have to introduce all of them but your code still introduce len 10 ! have a look at my answer !

Comment: @Kasra, you don't need to check beyond 10, when you count to 11 do you count to 10 first or after? You are also creating a list for no reason.

Comment: hey .. i got the point ! i review the question i miss some things ! +!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s1 = '23971500000239713000002344550000023971900000'
>>> s2 = '23971500000239719000002344550000023971600000'
>>> minlen = 10

>>> subs = (s1[ii:ii+minlen] for ii in range(len(s1) - minlen + 1))
>>> any(sub in s2 for sub in subs)
True
```

That is, generate all possible substrings of the minimum length in one of the strings, and check if they are in the other string.

Of course there are more efficient solutions if you have incredibly long strings (see [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) for inspiration), but the above seems to do what you want and is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
str1 = "23971500000239713000002344550000023971900000"
str2 = "23971500000239719000002344550000023971600000"

def subsearch(str1, str2):
    for i in range(len(str1)-9):
        if str1[i:10+i:] in str2:
           return True
    return False

print subsearch(str1, str2)
>>True
```

Comment: So my mistake was that the substrings have to be chunked up into blocks of 11, 0:10, 11:22, etc...so I want to search over the four blocks of 11 for the first string.  Not every single possible substring.  I am trying to modify this but having difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = '23971500000239713000002344550000023971900000'
s2 = '23971500000239719000002344550000023971600000'

def find_all_substrings(s):
    return [ s[i:i+10] for i in range(len(s)) if len(s[i:i+10]) == 10 ]

common_substrings = [s for s in find_all_substrings(s1) if s in s2]
```

You question is fuzzy once you've decided that there is a common string. But the condition is true when `len(common_strings) > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, below is a solution in regex just to show the possibility.

I do not recommend the use of this solution in production code.

```
import re

s1 = "23971500000239713000002344550000023971900000"
s2 = "23971500000239719000002344550000023971600000"

# Since both strings contain only digits, ~ can be safely used as separator
s = s1 + '~' + s2
```

Find a match:

```
re.match(r'^\d*?(\d{10,})\d*~\d*\1', s)
```

Find all longest match from a certain index:

```
r = re.compile(r'(\d{10,})\d*~\d*\1')
o = [r.match(s, i) for i in range(0, len(s1))]

# Print result
print([i.group(1) if i else None for i in o])
```

Output for the example:

> `['2397150000023971', '397150000023971', '97150000023971', '7150000023971', '150000023971', '50000023971', '0000023971', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '000002344550000023971', '00002344550000023971', '0002344550000023971', '002344550000023971', '02344550000023971', '2344550000023971', '344550000023971', '44550000023971', '4550000023971', '550000023971', '50000023971900000', '0000023971900000', '000023971900000', '00023971900000', '0023971900000', '023971900000', '23971900000', '3971900000', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`

You need to write a bit more code to remove matches that are suffix of previous match.